# Understanding 2 transactions

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap, pancakeswap

I was analyzing some transactions on new coins, and I faced the following.

Here are the two transactions

1. https://bscscan.com/tx/0xaccf8362a721ac83f2f8778ca0f86f7a97e6794b50eaae51dfa7d143776fb63d
2. https://bscscan.com/tx/0xf8c150272580fe963901b92e1b4770afcf7e5e2618bac7a49b4b1f73286c1ccd

The 1st spent 3,360,745,934 of the coin to get 0.2BNB
The 2nd spent 6,832,681,846 of the coin to get 0.01BNB

So basically, the 2nd one spent twice the value of the first to get 20 times less?

Those 2 transactions have been done in a short period of time, so I don't think that the slippage is responsible for this (I may be wrong).

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

its price is "$0.000000000009506". if you see [coinmarket data](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/floki-ceo/)

[image]

its market cap is low and volume is low. If there is low liquidity for the coin, it can lead to higher slippage and a larger difference between the expected and actual exchange rates. In those coins, order book prices do not increase by a small amount. there might be a huge difference between two consecutive sell orders. you could check the order book of the exchange

Comment: Hum thanks for your answer, however checking few transactions to this coin, only this one is extremely low compare to the others and I can't find the "why"